# If conforme função

Tags: jquery, if

Como definir um "IF" rode conforme texto de uma "var"?
Ex:

```js
var Ativar = {
 ativo: 'sim'
};
```

Pretendo usar o o "sim" para "IF" validar e executar. Alguém sabe como fazer?

Perdão sobre minha explicação. Espero que entendam minha pretensão. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se foi isso o que você quis dizer, mas tente assim:

```
if(ativar.ativo == 'sim'){
    //função
}
```

Não esqueça de declarar as variáveis sempre com a primeira letra minúscula("var ativar = {}")

Comment: Exatamente isso, caiu ferrugem dos meus olhos quando vi o A maiúsculo ali. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Sem problemas. Conseguiu alcançar o resultado que precisava?

Comment: Desculpa a demora na resposta. Devido a política do Stack, não pude responder antes. Sim o problema foi sanado. Era apenas o erro na var. Obrigado.

Comment: Certo, fico feliz.